# Disable tilt to x and z axis with threejs & ammojs

Tags: three.js, ammo.js

I want to drop a soft body on a ground with threejs & ammojs.
My goal is, that it stays at his position on the x and the z axis - so just fall down at the y axis - currently its rolling away.
So far i've got this: https://jsfiddle.net/mwgrtfhp/

I tried to disable updating the x and z variables at the `updatePhysics()` function - but then the object still tilts.
Also tried to use different geometry functions but i think thats a ammojs 'problem'.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done via "pinning" the inertia tensor. I tried doing it in your jsfiddle though and it wasn't working... maybe it doesn't apply to soft bodies? Basically you set the inertia tensor to 0 for the axis' you dont want to spin and nonzero for the axis it's allowed to spin on. It's commonly used for character controllers where you want a cylinder or capsule to always remain upright. I suppose you could also just set the rotation to the identity quaternion 0,0,0,1 each frame.. that might work.. Sorry I can't be more help...

Comment: thanks man! just tried to set quaternion on update to `0, 0, 0, 1` - but sadly does not have any impact